# please help cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file, input, cmd

im new to cmd commands and im trying to make at least a batch file to open 3 different websites with different keys for my girlfriend, so i've tried this:

```
@echo off
title (something)
color 05
echo (welcome)
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo choose music
echo to listen to song one. press 1
echo to listen to song two. press 2
echo to listen to song three. press 3
set/p input= You choose:
if %input% == 1 goto Song one
:Song one
echo opening song one
start chrome "link1"
pause
:exit
echo choose music
echo to listen to song one. press 1
echo to listen to song two. press 2
echo to listen to song three. press 3
set/p input= You choose:
if %input% == 2 goto song two
:song two
echo opening song two
start chrome "link2"
pause
:exit
echo choose music
echo to listen to song one. press 1
echo to listen to song two. press 2
echo to listen to song three. press 3
set/p input= You choose:
if %input% == 3 goto Song one
:Song three
echo opening song three
start chrome "link3"
pause
:exit
```

and the input seems to be messed up, i can type W and it will work as if it was either 1, 2 or 3, other problem is, it wont correspond to the numbers, if i want to open 3 and press 3 it opens 1, then again it goes to 2, then 3, after 3 cmd crashes, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your script. It should be more like this:

```
@echo off
cls
title (something)
color 05
echo (welcome)
echo.
echo.
echo.

:PickAgain
echo Choose music:
echo To listen to song one, press 1.
echo To listen to song two, press 2.
echo To listen to song three, press 3.
echo To quit, press 4.
set/p input= You choose:

if %input% == 1 goto Song1
if %input% == 2 goto Song2
if %input% == 3 goto Song3
if %input% == 4 goto Quit
goto PickAgain

:Song1
echo opening song one
start chrome "link1"
goto PickAgain

:Song2
echo opening song two
start chrome "link2"
goto PickAgain

:Song3
echo opening song three
start chrome "link3"
goto PickAgain

:Quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I took the liberty of making your script much cleaner, while solving your problem.

Here's the code for your new Batch File:

```
@echo off
Color 09
Title (Something)
Echo Welcome
:Start
Cls
Echo To listen to song 1, press 1.
Echo To listen to song 2, press 2.
Echo To listen to song 3, press 3.
Echo To quit, press 4.
Choice /c 1234 >nul
If %errorlevel%==1 start chrome.exe (Link1) & goto start
If %errorlevel%==2 start chrome.exe (Link2) & goto start
If %errorlevel%==3 start chrome.exe (Link3) & goto start
Exit
```

By the way any code that looks like

'If %errorlevel%==1 start chrome.exe (Link) & goto start'

Should be on ONE line.
Hope this helps!